AOT Chiseled version of .net sdk 9 not working
When I'm trying to build the following DockerFile for a WebAPI project running on Docker:
# This stage is used when running from VS in fast mode (Default for Debug configuration)
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:9.0-noble-chiseled-extra AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
USER app

# This stage is used to build the service project
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/sdk:9.0-noble-aot AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["CommonLibrary.Api/CommonLibrary.Api.csproj", "CommonLibrary.Api/"]
COPY ["CommonLibrary.Common/CommonLibrary.Common.csproj", "CommonLibrary.Common/"]
COPY ["CommonLibrary.Model/CommonLibrary.Model.csproj", "CommonLibrary.Model/"]
COPY ["CommonLibrary.Database/CommonLibrary.Database.csproj", "CommonLibrary.Database/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./CommonLibrary.Api/CommonLibrary.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/CommonLibrary.Api"
RUN dotnet build "./CommonLibrary.Api.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

# This stage is used to publish the service project to be copied to the final stage
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./CommonLibrary.Api.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# This stage is used in production or when running from VS in regular mode (Default when not using the Debug configuration)
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CommonLibrary.Api.dll"]

I'm getting the error:
 ERROR [CommonLibrary base 3/3] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl

My guess is that the chiseled versions of Linux don't include anything, but I'd like to install curl as that docker image has to run a healthcheck over docker compose.
In the WebApi project I have this three properties setup:
<InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
<EnableSdkContainerSupport>True</EnableSdkContainerSupport>
<PublishTrimmed>True</PublishTrimmed>
<PublishAot>True</PublishAot>

I'm trying to follow https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/releasesapi/Dockerfile.ubuntu-chiseled-icu and https://github.com/richlander/container-workshop/blob/main/publish-options.md without any success. Any idea or example on how to setup a WebAPI project running on AOT with docker compose on Ubuntu with Curl installed?
Thanks!

Unrelated to your question: You mention having PublishAot set to true, but this Dockerfile is running your app as though it wasn't published with AOT. Did you add the PublishAOT after you scaffolded the Dockerfile?

Yes I added that to the project properties

While I can't help you get curl installed, I can help you get a health check for ASP.NET on chiseled. The easiest thing to do is to add the health check as an option for your existing app (alternatively you can make a dedicated console app and add it to your image). The simplest version of this is:
if (args.Length == 1)
{
    System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    try
    {
        var res = await client.GetAsync(args[0]);
        if (res.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    Environment.Exit(-1);
}

This allows you to check the health of your app with:
dotnet CommonLibrary.Api.dll <url for your health probe>
-- or for AOT --
./CommonLibrary.Api <url for your health probe>

Thanks for your comment, at the end I'm not running the chisled version because it is really difficult to make it run, and relying on the compose healthchecks as before.
